# Why cannot access array's value when using Ext.Function.defer (setTimeout)?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm basically adding elements to an array using Ext.Function.defer and the elements are getting added to the array, but when I console out the array it outputs empty array. Here's my code:

```
   var arr = [];
    Ext.Function.defer(function () {
        Ext.Array.forEach(me.query('grid'), function (grid) {
            arr.push(grid.collapseTool.getId()); // [1 ,4 , 6 , 8 ,10]
        });
    }, 1000);
    console.log(arr); // outputs empty array []
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because defer will run asynchronously, you are accessing `arr` in a state where it is not populated with the data you want to

**Edit:** You can test this code to understand defer

```
Ext.Function.defer(function() {
    console.log("You will see this message later although it is written first");
}, 1000);
console.log("You will see this message first although it is written after");
```

**Edit2:** Sample code

```
Ext.Function.defer(function() {
    var arr = [];
    Ext.Array.forEach(panel.query('grid'), function(grid) {
        arr.push(grid.collapseTool.getId());
    });
    onDone(arr);
}, 1000);

function onDone(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: Sure, can you provide more code so I can know where you want it to be outputted? (btw answer edited to understand defer)

Comment: I got it, however where do you want to output the array to? If you just want it to be on console you can just put inside the defer function

Comment: I don't want to output it inside of the defer. I want to output it outside of the defer because I will use the array for other functions

Comment: Due to the fact that it is asynchronous, you can only use Promise or callback to output the array

Comment: Post updated, `Promise` doesn't work using `Function.defer` because it is just a wrapper for `setTimeout`